# My file reader program, needs to print in columns, printing in one long line?

Tags: java, filereader

```java
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static TreeMap<String, Integer> generateFrequencyList()
        throws IOException {
        TreeMap<String, Integer> wordsFrequencyMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        String file = "file1.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                token = removePunctuation(token);
                if (!wordsFrequencyMap.containsKey(token.toLowerCase())) {
                    wordsFrequencyMap.put(token.toLowerCase(), 1);
                } else {
                    int count = wordsFrequencyMap.get(token.toLowerCase());
                    wordsFrequencyMap.put(token.toLowerCase(), count + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return wordsFrequencyMap;
    }

    private static String removePunctuation(String token) {
        token = token.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll("\\.","").replaceAll(";","").replaceAll("!","");
        return token;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            TreeMap<String, Integer> freqMap = generateFrequencyList();
            System.out.println(freqMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code reads a .txt file and returns me each word in the file and its frequency, I need it to give me the percentage and print all of it in 3 columns. I'm having a bit of trouble getting that to work, right now it just prints one long line, anyone have some ideas?

Comment: You can reduce your `removePunctuation` method to `return token.replaceAll("[,.;!]", "");`.

Comment: @WillLaPenta Please use correct indentation and [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) the next time you post a code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just printing the frequency map as is, instead you'll have to walk over the map and construct those three columns, you'll have to replace `System.out.println(freqMap);` with e.g.:

```
for(final Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : freqMap.entrySet()) {
    final String key = entry.getKey();
    final Integer value = entry.getValue();
    final float percentage = /* calculate percentage here */ ;

    System.out.println(key + " = " + value + " => " + percentage);
}
```

---

You'll have to calculate the percentage yourself, of course, since the `TreeMap` only contains the absolute frequencies, e.g.

```
float total = 0;
for (final Integer wordCount : freqMap.values()) {
    total += wordCount;
}
// ...
    final float percentage = (value / total) * 100;
```

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I need but it seems like it is not reading all of the words now.

Comment: It seems to be only showing words from t-z in the alphabet

Comment: @WillLaPenta are you sure you aren't only seeing the bottom of the list because it scrolled out of reach? It does work in my test